# multiple validation error for a textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print specific emty error message as well as number error message for the age field while during the button click. for my code only the last error message is diplaying.
This is for Validation Purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                    var error = 0;
                    var name = $('#<%=txtName.ClientID%>').val();

                    if ($.trim(name) == '') {
                        $('#name_error_msg').text('Name cannot be Empty');
                        $('#name_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    } else
                        $('#name_error_msg').text('');


                    var country = $('#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>').val();
                    if (country == 0) {
                        $('#country_error_msg').text('Please select the Country');
                        $('#country_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        $('#country_error_msg').text('');



                    var age = $('#<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val();
                    if ($.trim(age) == '') {
                        $('#age_error_msg').text('Invalid Age');
                        $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    }

                    var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
                    if (!filter.test(age)) {
                        $('#age_error_msg').text('Invalid Age');
                        $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        $('#age_error_msg').text('');


                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if (!filter.test(emailReg)) {
                        $('#email_error_msg').text('Invalid email format');
                        $('#email_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#email_error_msg').text('');
                    }
                    var email = $('#<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>').val();
                    if ($.trim(email) == '') {
                        $('#email_error_msg').text('Email cannot be Empty');
                        $('#email_error_msg').parent().show();
                        error = 1;
                    } else {
                        $('#email_error_msg').text('');
                    }



                    if (!($('#<%=ChkAgree.ClientID%>').is(':checked'))) {
                        error = 1;
                        $('#check_error_msg').html("Please Tick the Agree to Terms of Use.");
                        $('#check_error_msg').parent().show();
                    }
                    else
                        $('#check_error_msg').html(" ");

                    if (error) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                });


            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Remove `else`. have only `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is, replace:

```
var age = $('#<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val();
if ($.trim(age) == '') {
    $('#age_error_msg').text('Invalid Age');
    $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
    error = 1;
}

var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
if (!filter.test(age)) {
    $('#age_error_msg').text('Invalid Age');
    $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
    error = 1;
}
else
    $('#age_error_msg').text('');
```

with:

```
var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
var age = $('#<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val();
if ( $.trim(age) == '' || !filter.test(age)) {
    $('#age_error_msg').text('Invalid Age');
    $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
    error = 1;
} else {
    $('#age_error_msg').text('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp variable to add up each error.

```
                var age_errors = [];
                var age = $('#<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val();
                if ($.trim(age) == '') {
                    age_errors.push('Age is empty');
                    $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
                    error = 1;
                }

                var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
                if (!filter.test(age)) {
                    age_errors.push('Invalid Age number');   
                    $('#age_error_msg').parent().show();
                    error = 1;
                }
                // set the error: empty string or a comma-separated list.
                $('#age_error_msg').text(age_errors.join(', '));
```